# SwiftUI Binding Test for Button And Picker

Tags: swiftui, binding

I would like to make a test with SwiftUI binding.
Aim was changing Picker selection with a button and with an other Picker.

In following code ContentView2's Picker selection will be changed with button in ContentView and Picker in ContentView1.

Button can change ContentView2 picker selection but ContentView1 Picker does not.

I can not find the reason.

You can copy paste code to test.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var index1 = 0
@State private var index2 = 1

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { mainView in
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                if index2 == 0 {
                    index2 = 1
                } else {
                    index2 = 0
                }
                    }) {
                        Text("Button")
                    }
            ContentView1(pickerIndex: $index1)
            ContentView2(pickerIndex: $index2)
        }
    }
}
}



struct ContentView1: View {

@State var pickerData = ["Data1", "Data2"]
@Binding var pickerIndex: Int
@State var pickerIndex2 = 0


var customLabel0: some View{
       HStack {
           VStack(spacing: 10) {
           Text("Picker One")
                   .foregroundColor(.black)
          
           Text(pickerData[pickerIndex])
                   .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
           }
           .foregroundColor(.white)
       }
       .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - (2.5 * 8 )) * 0.6 * 0.5, height: 100)
       .background(Color.gray)
       .cornerRadius(5)
   }


@State private var testIndex = 1


var body: some View {
 
  
    Menu {
        Picker("", selection: self.$pickerIndex) {
            ForEach(0..<pickerData.count, id: \.self) {index in
                Text(pickerData[index])
            }
        }
    } label: {
        customLabel0
    }
    .onChange(of: pickerIndex, perform: {_ in
       
        ContentView2(pickerIndex: $pickerIndex)
       
        })
    
    
}

}




struct ContentView2: View {

@State var pickerData = ["Data1", "Data2"]
@Binding var pickerIndex: Int




var customLabel0: some View{
       HStack {
           VStack(spacing: 10) {
           Text("Picker Two")
                   .foregroundColor(.black)
          
           Text(pickerData[pickerIndex])
                   .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
           }
           .foregroundColor(.white)
       }
       .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - (2.5 * 8 )) * 0.6 * 0.5, height: 100)
       .background(Color.gray)
       .cornerRadius(5)
   }


var body: some View {
    
    
    
      Menu {
         Picker("", selection: $pickerIndex) {
              ForEach(0..<pickerData.count, id: \.self) {index in
                  Text(pickerData[index])
              }
          }
      } label: {
          customLabel0
      }
      .onChange(of: pickerIndex, perform: {_ in
     
        
         
          })
      
    
}
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

Comment: You can't use `ContentView2(pickerIndex: $pickerIndex)` inside .`onChange(of:)`: inside the closure of this modifier you need to provide lines of code as you do in a function, not call a View. You need to use a view model to solve what you want to accomplish, or bind the variables in the same view.

Comment: And don't ignore your warnings. You have a warning "Result of 'ContentView2' initializer is unused" in your `.onChange(of:)`. This tells you that the view won't display within that block. When we write views in SwiftUI, we are describing how a view should display. A view is not an action that we can call. You need to change some state in the `.onChange(of:)` that will cause your view to display as you wish.

Comment: what is some state in that case ?  $pickerIndex is a state but it refuse to be changed from other view. I think swiftUI have long way to go

Comment: And how the button is working when onChange does not work